# how to rename keys with matching pattern in redis

Tags: php, sql, redis

I have 1000 of keys like :

alpha_123_dubai_2015

wherein I want to rename the key names as :

live_123_dubai_2015

I am new to Redis found some suggestions below :

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> RENAME key1 key2

But I don't want to specify whole key name and just want to execute similar query to below sql query in redis :

update tablename set new_key = '2' where key like '%1%'
That is in above scenario we just want to replace the value 1 of key1 with value 2 and new key formed will look like key2

Kindly suggest.

Comment: is there any pattern in all these keys? i.e. all are starting with `aplha` and you want to change it with `live`, or you want to change first word (whatever it is) with `live` and year (which is always at the end) with current year... in general - give us more examples and desired output.

Comment: yes, correct i want to rename all keys which have starting pattern as alpha as replace the whole key name with new key name as : live_xyz_123_abs

Comment: what about year in that case?

Comment: While Renaming name of keys starting with alpha it would be replaced with new key having latest year or detail.

Comment: Example : key_1=alpha_123_abc   with below update command update tablename set new_key = 'live_456_xyz' where key_1 like '%alpha%'   key_1 will now have the value as 'live_456_xyz'

Comment: It would also be helpfull for us if I can replace only the part of key that I just want to replace the work "alpha" with "live" in keys